# dependency injection and runtime dependency .NET best design pattern

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I want to use dependency injection in this case :

I have n IXMLParsers abstractions, each one have one or more implementation.
  i check database for active IXMLParsers.
  For each active IXMLParser, i instantiate the correct implementation (but this is against DI ??? )

So what's  the best design pattern for doing this.

Comment: In my opinion you're trying to do something like a class factory.

Answer (score 3):

You can inject a Factory that will create a desired IXMLParser

```
interface IXmlParserFactory
{
    IXMLParser CreateParser();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can format your Constructor to take the argument as

example

```
Class A
{
  IXMLParsers parser=null;

   A(IXMLParsers p)
   {
     parser=p;
    }
}
```

now you may create different type of parses as needed and send to the constructor

example

```
     A obj1=new A(new Type1Parser);
     A obj2=new A(new Type2Parser);
     A obj3=new A(new Type3Parser);
```

etc....